# FlyWeight Pattern: every object parameters became same as updated

Tags: c#, design-patterns, xna

Hello everyone ı have a problem with flyweight patter ;

I try to implement flyweight patter to  my sprite class. There are tons of smilarty as attributes each Sprite object only diffirences are Position and frame;

Im my code ı have a problem, whenever ı set(Position or frame) of one sprite , every other objects attribute also change, ı dont want that ı want  most of attributes are same but frame and position is diffrent for each object.

Here is the code:

```
public enum Type
    {
        sprite,
        None,

    };
    public class FactorySprite 
    {
        private LinkList SpriteList = new LinkList();
        private Hashtable  Sprites = new Hashtable();
        public FactorySprite() 
        {
           // SpriteList.AddtoBegining(new Sprite());
            Sprites.Add(Type.sprite, new Sprite());
        }
        public GameSprite getSprite(Type type) 
        {
            //  return (Sprite)SpriteList.Search(O);
            GameSprite gamesprite = null;
            if(Sprites.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                gamesprite =( GameSprite)Sprites[type];

            }
          return gamesprite;
        }

    } 

    public abstract class GameSprite 
    {
        protected Texture2D texture;
       // protected Vector2 position;
        protected Texture loadTexture;
       // protected int frame;
        protected Vector2 Speed;
        protected Rectangle SourceRectangle;
        protected Color color;
        public Type type;
        protected SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public abstract void Draw();
        public  abstract void Update();
        public abstract void setframe(int frame_number);
        public abstract void setPosition(int x,int y);

    }

    public  class Sprite : GameSprite
    {
       private  int frame;
       private Vector2 position;
        public Sprite()
        {
            frame =0;
            type = Type.sprite;
            spriteBatch = Game1.GameInstance.spriteBatch;
            texture = Texture.Instance().GetTexture();

            Speed = new Vector2(0, 1);
            color = Color.White;

        }

        public override void Draw()
        {

            spriteBatch.Draw(texture,position,Image.Instance().drawframe(this.frame), color);

        }
        public override void setframe(int frame_number) {this.frame = frame_number; }
        public override void setPosition(int x, int y)  {this.position = new Vector2(x, y); }
        public  Type getType() 
        { 
            return type;
        } 
        public override void Update(){}
    }
```

Here is manin that ı create factory flayweight and each object that ı create

```
SpriteManager sm = SpriteManager.Instance();

FactorySprite factory = new FactorySprite();
Sprite s1 = (Sprite)factory.getSprite(Type.sprite);
s1.setframe(6);
s1.setPosition(200, 300);
sm.AddSprite(s1);
Sprite s2 = (Sprite)factory.getSprite(Type.sprite);
s2.setframe(5);
s2.setPosition(100, 100);
sm.AddSprite(s2);
```

Problem here to be more clear s1 and s2  has same frame and position(whic one is last updated all other object become same)

Answer (score 4):

This thing about the FlyWeight pattern is that every time you ask for one, you get the same instance. Thus every time you call GetSprite you are returning the same one, not a copy but the same one.

So if you call it twice, you now have two references to the same object. If you change it in one place it will change in the other because the two ARE THE SAME THING! That's actually the point of the FlyWeight pattern.

I would suggest that you don't use this pattern where you need *different* objects as you do.

One way around trhis is to extract all this bits of a Sprite which do not ever change into a new class, which you can then use the FlyWeight pattern on. The changeable bits would stay in the Sprite class, with the addition of a reference to your new 'ImutableSprite' instance.

Answer (score 2):

The Flyweight pattern doesn't apply here.

Flyweight means that you use the *same* object with a specific in all cases where you want this specific value. Obviously, if you change the value in one place, the change will appear everywhere.

If you want to reduce the number of sprites, you could use immutable semantics: Use a single Sprite instance for a specific set of Position,Frame and create a copy when you want a Sprite with a different set.